# LINQ to XML query ignorance

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Very new to LINQ to XML.

I have the following document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DIDemo>
    <PurchaseOrders>
        <PurchaseOrder date="2011-11-15" purchaseordernumber="PO-1234-1234" suppliername="The Greatest Supplier">
            <LineItems>
                <LineItem productcode="PRD-001" productname="A Cool Product" quantity="3" unitprice="276.99"/>
                <LineItem productcode="PRD-056" productname="A Unique Product" quantity="5" unitprice="316.99"/>
            </LineItems>
        </PurchaseOrder>

        <PurchaseOrder date="2011-11-11" purchaseordernumber="PO-1231-1231" suppliername="The Largest Supplier">
            <LineItems>
                <LineItem productcode="PRD-025" productname="A Useful Product" quantity="8" unitprice="96.99"/>
                <LineItem productcode="PRD-014" productname="A Wonderful Product" quantity="1" unitprice="916.99"/>
            </LineItems>
        </PurchaseOrder>
    </PurchaseOrders>
</DIDemo>
```

And I'm trying a very simple query to get the Purchase Order based on the purchaseordernumber attribute. The end goal being to create a c# object out of the Purchase Order node (attributes and line items).

The query I'm trying is the following (I broke it up in pieces to try and see where's the issue):

```
    var document = XDocument.Load(PurchaseOrdersFilePath);
    var partial1 = document.Element("PurchaseOrders"); //This returns null
    var partial2 = partial1.Elements("PurchaseOrder"); //This one blows up
    var final = partial2.Single(po => po.Attribute("purchaseordernumber") == criterion.PropertyValue);
```

If this doesn't work. What would be the correct way to query this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the document root as base:

```
var partial1 = document.Root.Element("PurchaseOrders");
```

Alternatively and probably easier in your case you can use `Descendants()` to query for all `PurchaseOrder` nodes on all levels in the XML document:

```
var orders = document.Descendants("PurchaseOrder");
```

And of course you can combine this in the final result:

```
var order = document.Descendants("PurchaseOrder")
                    .Single(po => (string)po.Attribute("purchaseordernumber") == criterion.PropertyValue);
```

Comment: Thank you. The Descendants option was the one that worked. The Root.Element option threw an "InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements" exception on the Single statement.

Answer (score 1):

To find elements anywhere in the document you can use `Descendants`.

Related:

- [LINQ to XML - XElement - Descendants vs. Elements](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/zuker/archive/2009/01/15/linq-to-xml-xelement-descendants-vs-elements.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the outermost element of the file is not `<PurchaseOrders>` but `<DIDemo>`. And once `partial1` is null, dereferencing it is going to cause your program to blow up.